# Почему при 1 варианте код работает как мне нужно, а во втором возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
from random import *
l=[8,6,8,566,'»']

#1 вариант
shuffle(l)
print(l)

#2 вариант
print(shuffle(l))
```

Comment: Потому что функция shuffle никогда ничего не возвращает

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 5):

Потому, что функция `shuffle` просто перемешивает значения списка, но **не** возвращает его. Пользуйтесь первым вариантом.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже объяснили, `shuffle` возвращает `None`. Но если очень хочется написать код в одну строчку можно использовать например такой трюк:

```py
print(shuffle(l) or l)
```

`None` в логическом выражении будет считаться как `False`, поэтому значением выражения `shuffle(l) or l` будет часть после `or`, то есть `l`, причём взято оно будет уже после выполнения вызова `shuffle(l)`. Таким образом можно в одной конструкции и вызвать `shuffle(l)` и получить значение `l` для печати.